# Vue cli 3 do some tasks after build

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I am using `vue cli 3` and here is my `vue.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const publicDir = 'public'
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
module.exports = {
  publicPath: isProduction ? './dist/' : '',
  outputDir: 'public/dist',
  indexPath: '../../resources/views/index.blade.php',
  filenameHashing: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .entry('app')
      .clear()
      .add('./resources/vue/main.js')
      .end()
    config.module
      .rule('graphql')
      .test(/\.gql$/)
      .use('graphql-tag/loader')
      .loader('graphql-tag/loader')
      .end()
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)]
  }
}
```

I need to delete some files after build for production and I don't know **how to detect the build process is over**.

I didn't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in your `package.json` file. You can add your custom script or the modify existing one.

For example take a look at the **clean** script. You can call this script manually, or add it in another script. In this example it is executed when **build** script is executed:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "watch": "vue-cli-service build --mode development --watch",
    "dev": "vue-cli-service --mode development build",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build && npm run clean",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "clean": "rm -rf ../public/dist"
  },
  ...
```

**NOTE**: `&&` makes them run sequentially **`clean` will run after `build`**.

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it works and that's enough :)) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a `postbuild` script:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "postbuild": "rm dist/<file-to-delete>", // <--- add this one
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  }
```

Comment: This explains why it works: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts