# How to write a JSON file into the dist folder by vue.config.js webpack config?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

The origin data is not from a file, but from a JSON object.

I already know how to use the native Node.js code to write a JSON file into the dist directory, but now I want to use vue.config.js webpack config to do this task.

I'm not familiar with webpack either. I simply checked some information, but I didn't find any way.

I hope to get some advice, thanks!

Comment: This is not a job for Webpack. Just use a separate node script

Comment: vue.config.js is javascript, just call your method anywhere you want in this file, it will just work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue cli 3 do some tasks after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57556194/vue-cli-3-do-some-tasks-after-build)

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution.

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra');

function JsonWebpackPlugin() {
  fs.writeJSONSync('./public/some.json', { a: 1 });
}
JsonWebpackPlugin.prototype.apply = new Function();

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack(config) {
        config.plugin('Json').use(JsonWebpackPlugin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).